# DOM Node Count Increasing - .off() .empty()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, widget, event-listener

I am using an external JS Widget library called [jqWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/) mainly for their feature rich GRIDS. I am building a Single Page Application that adds and removes LOTS of grids throughout the use of the application. I am having a problem with the DOM Node Count increasing, I've managed to make a dent in the Event Listener Count, although that is slowly creeping up as well. Example:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#runTest").on('click', function(){

            $("#testGrid").jqxGrid({
                width: 795,
                selectionmode: 'singlecell',
                editable: true,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                rowsheight: 20,
                height: 200,
                columns: [
                    {text: 'Activity ID', datafield: 'activity_id', width: 150},
                    {text: 'Description', datafield: 'activity_description', width: 150},
                    { text: 'Notes&nbsp;&frasl;&nbsp;Comments', datafield: 'activity_notes'}
                ]
            }); 

        });

        $("#destroyGrid").on('click', function(){

            $("#runTest").off('click');
            $("#testGrid").jqxGrid('destroy');
            $("#testDiv").remove();

        }); 

    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='testDiv'>
   <div id='testGrid'></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="click me" id="runTest" />
<input type="button" value="destroy" id="destroyGrid" />
```

When click the *runTest* button to create the grid, my 
**DOM Node Count** goes from **318** to **880** 
and 
**Event Listener Count** from **8** to **132**.

After I click the *destroy* button (and Garbage Collection occurs), the 
**DOM Node Count** goes from **880** to **645**
and 
**Event Listener Count** from **132** to **32**.

Theoretically shouldn't the values return to the original state? Am I missing something here? I've read through tons of posts on this subject and I seem to be following the standard practices so I am tempted to think this is an issue with the jqWidget library and not my code, any help or advice is appreciated.

I've tried empty() and remove() with the same results.

Comment: How does the number of dom nodes being added relate to the number of rows being added? basically, i'm trying to figure out what elements could possibly be getting left behind, possibly attached to a private var or similar.

Comment: @KevinB this has to be the case, because when you inspect the document through the Chrome Dev Tools, there is nothing there, however it reads that there is still 645 Dom Nodes, why arent these being collected in the GC?

Comment: Unless you can get access to the source of jqWidgets, that's about as far as we can dig. I've only been able to get minified code.

Comment: @KevinB so you agree that this must be an issue with their library? Should I be doing anything different in my code? It appears that I have correctly removed the event listener, destroyed the widget, and emptied the div, correct?

Comment: Yes, your code all looks fine. I suspect it to be the library.

Comment: Does jqWidgets still come with jQuery 1.7?

Comment: I think it comes with 1.9, but i am using the latest release of jquery, downloaded the newest one last week...

Comment: If you continued initializing and removing several times, do the counts continue to rise?

Comment: Yes, they continue to rise. This is my concern, after hours of using the app the counts could grow very large. And this is just a very basic example...

Comment: You can see that some of the events and dom nodes are properly deleted/garbage collected, however there is still a non trivial amount still left lingering around.

Comment: Yup, i see a possible place where it could be happening. there are several cases where within the library element.innerHTML = "" is being used to empty elements. if those elements ever had any jquery events bound to them, that event data and the element are both still being referenced inside jQuery, therefore they can't be gc'd. Not really much you can do about it aside from complain to the author.

Comment: would it help to manually change those lines to something like .empty() ? worth a shot or no?

Comment: Probably not worth it without knowing what those lines actually do, but it wouldn't be difficult to try.